# How to sum columns of jquery datatable on search event or filter event

Tags: jquery, search, datatable, event-handling, column-sum

I want to show sum of a particular column in footer. But as I apply filter/search to JQuery Data Table I also want to sum to change according to number of rows remaining in the filtered table.

I am sharing one possible approach.
Please suggest me better approaches.

Comment: Is there a specific problem with the approach you have shared? What would make a different approach better than yours - how would you decide?

Comment: Please don't "share" something as an answer. If you have details for your question, use [edit], and if you're answering the question (and not expecting answers anymore) then use answer